# MSSQL: multiple INSERTs with PHP arrays and echoing back the data

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a form with the following structure:

```
<input type="text" name="projNo[1]" id="projNo[1]" value="<?php echo $row['ProjNo'
[1];>"
/>
<input type="text" name="projBudget[1]" id="projBudget[1]" value="<?php echo
$row['ProjBudget'][1]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="projDateFrom[1]" id="projDateFrom[1]" value="<?php echo
$row['ProjDateFrom'][1]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="projDateTo[1]" id="projDateTo[1]" value="<?php echo 
$row['ProjDateTo'][1]; ?>" />

<input type="text" name="projNo[2]" id="projNo[2]" value="<?php echo $row['ProjNo'
[2];>"
/>
<input type="text" name="projBudget[2]" id="projBudget[2]" value="<?php echo
$row['ProjBudget'][2]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="projDateFrom[2]" id="projDateFrom[2]" value="<?php echo
$row['ProjDateFrom'][2]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="projDateTo[2]" id="projDateTo[2]" value="<?php echo 
$row['ProjDateTo'][2]; ?>" />
```

There are two more groups like this with indexes 3 and 4. Upon submit, four separate records must be created in the DB if the user has filled in all four lines. My question is twofold: How would I structure my query to accomplish this? And: Have I set up my code correctly? When the form is loaded, I would like the correct output to be displayed. I've never been confronted with a request like this before, so I'm flying a bit blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PDO and prepared statements. Prepare a statement like this:

```
$s = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO PROJECT (no, budget, from, to) VALUES (?,?,?,?)')
```

Execute the statement for each set like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=4; $i++) {
    $s->execute(array($projNo[$i], $projBudget[$i], $projDateFrom[$i], $projDateTo[$i]));
}
```

(You need to add error checking and validation. This includes something that loads the stuff from $_POST to the arrays  I used in the above example.)

Currently, you have a XSS security issue in your code. You cannot just `echo` stuff that comes from the user - you need to escape it. If you are putting it inside HTML, including double-quoted attribute values like in your case, use `echo htmlspecialchars($_GET[...]);`.

You may want to create a "htmlout" function that does nothing else than echo htmlspecialchars, just to have a nicer, easier-to-write name for it, and use it everywhere. That way, you can search your code for instances of "echo", and unless you have protected them otherwise, this indicates you probably need to add some escaping.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this as soon as I'm back in the office. I already use PDO and parameterized statements, so this all makes sense to me. If it works, I'll mark it correct.